# Casting a String in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, time, casting

I have this query that extracts a numeric value of date which is programmed in the database a very long time ago and displays it as 19930215.202300000.  So for three different columns what I've done so far is cast the string as Date and Time

Existing Query:

```
 select SerialNum as [Serial Number],ts_sitename As Site,(case m.Scratched
 when 0 then 'Live'
 when 1 then 'Free'
 END) as Status,  Note as Comment, (case Destroyed when 0 then 'NO'
 when 1 then 'YES' END) as [Destroyed], 
 SUBSTRING(cast(EffectiveDate as char), 1, 8) AS [Effective Date Added], 
 SUBSTRING(cast(EffectiveDate as char), 10, 6) AS [Effective Time Added], 
 SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 1, 8) AS [Scratched Date], 
 SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 10, 6) AS [Scratched Time], 
 SUBSTRING(cast(ChangedPurgeDate as char), 1, 8) AS [Purge Date], 
 SUBSTRING(cast(ChangedPurgeDate as char), 10, 6) AS [Purge Time], 
 (select fl_filename from TheFiles_tab where mg_filenum = fl_filenum) as [Dataset],
 (select hs_hostname from TheHosts_tab where mg_hostnum = hs_hostnum) as [Host], 
 (select UserCode from [User] where mg_usernum = UserId) as [UserCode]
 from ((Media m left join MediaGenT g on m.MediaId = g.mg_medianum) 
 join TheSites_tab s on m.SiteId = s.ts_sitenum) 
 join Note n on m.NoteId = n.NoteId;
```

So this displays Effective Date as 20120327

However the required output is `2012-03-27`

Current display of effective time as 213100

Required output is 21:31:00

.. and so on for the other four date and time columns as well.

Please note I'm using SQL Server 2008 to run my queries.

Can anyone make any edits to my code to get the required output, I'm just not that great with string maniupulation? I would love to test it out immediately.

Comment: @marc_s I'm using MSSQL 2008 Server Management Studio.  Have also added it in the question.

Comment: [Please stop casting as char without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: @Aaronbertrand Is it possible for us to set up a chat? I'm just having trouble finishing this and am trying to meet a deadline.

Comment: @omarK Frankly, from looking at your questions it sounds like it's time to calm down, take a step back, read a few books about SQL and databases or hire someone.

Comment: To add to the above: No offense, but your comments to the answers below also show a lack of understanding, time pressure, and a "givemetehcodez" feel. I'll let you in on a little secret: we all have our own jobs to do and deadlines, and as far as I know nobody is getting paid to answer questions here on SO. It's a community of people helping people, and you're honestly not making yourself a good candidate to be helped.

Comment: I wish I could give bounty points for @lc. 's comments.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use this to integrate into your code.

```
declare @d decimal(20,9)
declare @yy varchar(4)
declare @mm varchar(2)
declare @dd varchar(2)
declare @hh varchar(2)
declare @mi varchar(2)
declare @tt varchar(2)
set @d = 19930215.202300000
set @yy = CAST(left(@d,4) as varchar)
set @mm = CAST(substring(cast(@d as varchar),5,2) as varchar)
set @dd = CAST(substring(cast(@d as varchar),7,2) as varchar)
set @hh = CAST(substring(cast(@d-floor(@d) as varchar),3,2) as varchar)
set @mi = CAST(substring(cast(@d-floor(@d) as varchar),5,2) as varchar)
set @tt = case when cast(@hh as int) > 12 then 'PM' else 'AM' end
select @d,@yy,@mm,@dd,@hh,@mi,@tt
```

this outputs something like this:

```
19930215.202300000,1993,02,15,20,23,PM
```

Comment: is it possible for you to add that to my code so I can test it? Im not too familiar with declaring and setting variables.

Comment: Sorry, I definately don't have time to write and debug your code with you.  I offered a suggestion on how to get the data you were looking for.  Hopefully it will help you reach a solution.

Answer (score 2):

First convert your value to DateTime then convert it to varchar(10) with 120 format.

```
SELECT 
    [Serial Number] = SerialNum 
 ,  [Site]          = ts_sitename
 ,  [Status]        = 
    (
        CASE m.Scratched
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Live'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Free'
        END
    ) 
 ,  [Comment]   =   Note
 ,  [Destroyed] =
    (
        CASE Destroyed 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'NO'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' 
        END
    ) 
,   [Effective Date Added]  = CONVERT(VARCHAR(CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR, EffectiveDate),       1, 8)), 120)
,   [Effective Time Added]  = CONVERT(VARCHAR(CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR, EffectiveDate),      10, 6)), 120)
,   [Scratched Date]        = CONVERT(VARCHAR(CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR, ScratchedDate),       1, 8)), 120)
,   [Scratched Time]        = CONVERT(VARCHAR(CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR, ScratchedDate),      10, 6)), 120)
,   [Purge Date]            = CONVERT(VARCHAR(CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR, ChangedPurgeDate),    1, 8)), 120)
,   [Purge Time]            = CONVERT(VARCHAR(CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR, ChangedPurgeDate),   10, 6)), 120)
,   [Dataset]               = (SELECT fl_filename from TheFiles_tab where mg_filenum = fl_filenum) 
,   [Host]                  = (SELECT hs_hostname from TheHosts_tab where mg_hostnum = hs_hostnum) 
,   [UserCode]              = (SELECT UserCode from [User] where mg_usernum = UserId) 
FROM ((Media m left join MediaGenT g on m.MediaId = g.mg_medianum) 
JOIN TheSites_tab s on m.SiteId = s.ts_sitenum) 
JOIN Note n on m.NoteId = n.NoteId;
```

Comment: This is for one specific year though. is it possible for you to apply this logic to the columns I've mentioned in my query so i can test it?